# How to sort and export all overlap key of value on dictionary of python?

Tags: python

For example, my dictionary contain this:

```
a = {1:'a',3:'b',2:'c',4:'d',1:'e',4:'f'}
```

To sort key on that list, I can do this:

```
b = []
for m in a:
     b.append(m) 
b.sort()
for value in b:
      print(a[value])
```

The problem is: 'd' and 'e' share the same value 4, and its only export one value. But I want to export all of them. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary, check what `a` contains

Comment: You can't do `b = b.sort()` the sort() method takes in-place and returns a None. Just do `b.sort()` and b gets sorted.

Comment: @Sayse i agree with you. Even if you have duplicate keys, the value that is defined later gets the key.

Comment: @TomKarzes it is possible, but it wouldn't work as intended. The earlier value for the key gets deleted

Comment: if the alphabets are not repeating, use them as the key

Comment: Yes that's what I said. Earlier value is overwritten. But you wouldn't get a TraceBack error tho

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is assigns a value to a key (or a key references a specific value). Therefore it is not possible to have a dictionary with the same key twice (check, what `a` looks like after assigning!).

What you may want to look at is a list of tuples!

```
a = [(1,'a'),(3,'b'),(2,'c'),(4,'d'),(1,'e'),(4,'f')]
```

After that, you can do the sorting just by doing this:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its worked. this is what I need

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate keys in a dictionary is not allowed. Your dict does not contain what you think.

```
>>> a = {1:'a',3:'b',2:'c',4:'d',1:'e',4:'f'}
>>> a
{1: 'e', 2: 'c', 3: 'b', 4: 'f'}
```

Answer (score 0):

When initializing your dictionary, the key 4 is defined twice: 4:'d', 4:'f'.

The second value 'f' overwrites the 'd' stored at a[4]. This is by design and therefore, you would need to correct your implementation to take this behaviour into account.